# Wordpress List Page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to convert my HTML to Wordpress theme. So my navigation is like this

```
<li><a href="">Home</a><small>Home</small></li>
<li><a href="">Flavors</a><small>Subtitle</small></li>
<li><a href="">About Us</a><small>Subtitle 2</small></li>
<li><a href="">Photos</a><small>Subtitle 3</small></li>
<li><a href="">Our Shop</a><small>Subtitle 4</small></li>
```

My code so far is

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="Home">Home</a><small>Home</small></li>
wp_list_pages('title_li=&link_after=<small>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'subtitle', true).'</small>');
```

As it goes, it doesn't work. I add a custom field subtitle for every page to put the Subtitle thing, but I can't call that in the wp_list_pages loop.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-menu-tricks/) a tutotial on adding subtitles to menu links you can try.